# Camera surface preview gives multiple errors on multiple devices

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

**The Problem:**

In using the camera on the device, I'm getting a number of errors.  I have looked over many answers here on StackOverflow and I have tried many solutions to no avail.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  I have tried this on two different devices and I'm getting the same errors.  This is failing on multiple devices...  Samsung Galaxy S7 and a Vankyo Z4 Tablet.  The logs are from the tablet.

```
2020-01-27 06:51:43.571 4182-4182/ W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-01-27 06:51:43.649 4182-4182/ D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-01-27 06:51:44.474 4182-4182/ E/Camera: Error 2
2020-01-27 06:51:44.600 4182-4262/ I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/rockchip/mali_so_src_of_midgard/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 1095; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
    arm_release_ver of this mali_so is 'r12p0-01rel0', rk_so_ver is '9@0 '.
2020-01-27 06:51:44.600 4182-4262/ I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/rockchip/mali_so_src_of_midgard/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 1101; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
    mali_ver_property has been set to 'r12p0-01rel0-x-9@0', to return.
2020-01-27 06:51:44.601 4182-4262/ I/mali_so: [File] : hardware/rockchip/mali_so_src_of_midgard/driver/product/cmem/src/mali_cmem_hoard.c; [Line] : 559; [Func] : should_current_process_not_to_use_hoard;
    WOULD use hoard.
2020-01-27 06:51:44.617 4182-4262/ I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-01-27 06:51:44.618 4182-4262/ I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-01-27 06:51:44.618 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-01-27 06:51:44.618 4182-4262/ D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-01-27 06:51:44.648 4182-4262/ D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-01-27 06:51:44.670 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:51:44.674 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:51:44.675 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setDisplayOrientation Failed: set display orientation failed
2020-01-27 06:51:44.677 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:51:45.630 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:51:45.818 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:51:46.014 4182-4262/ D/GRALLOC-ROCKCHIP: RK_GRAPHICS_VER=commit-id:69cd12f
2020-01-27 06:51:46.464 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1946ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=15482245744667, Vsync=15483533880219, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15483548307810, AnimationStart=15483548629227, PerformTraversalsStart=15483550124019, DrawStart=15483591003440, SyncQueued=15483639373153, SyncStart=15483640225986, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15483711543452, SwapBuffers=15484188006958, FrameCompleted=15484193184333, DequeueBufferDuration=14675000, QueueBufferDuration=3065000, 
2020-01-27 06:51:46.491 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:51:46.539 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=709ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=15483558409277, Vsync=15484219426205, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15484220349586, AnimationStart=15484220561045, PerformTraversalsStart=15484222148003, DrawStart=15484224182962, SyncQueued=15484224448962, SyncStart=15484224914753, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15484225396878, SwapBuffers=15484260477090, FrameCompleted=15484268449216, DequeueBufferDuration=11816000, QueueBufferDuration=3806000, 
2020-01-27 06:53:10.381 4182-4262/ W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xee0ea008 disconnect failed
2020-01-27 06:53:11.199 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:11.283 4182-4262/ D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-01-27 06:53:11.363 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:11.368 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 0
2020-01-27 06:53:11.369 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setDisplayOrientation Failed: set display orientation failed
2020-01-27 06:53:11.371 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:12.680 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 0
2020-01-27 06:53:12.691 4182-4182/ E/Camera: Error 2
2020-01-27 06:53:12.729 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:12.851 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1608ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=15568971643421, Vsync=15570446219645, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15570459148001, AnimationStart=15570459500626, PerformTraversalsStart=15570461186751, DrawStart=15570496844172, SyncQueued=15570546182510, SyncStart=15570546388427, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15570562532470, SwapBuffers=15570576764930, FrameCompleted=15570579908513, DequeueBufferDuration=7076000, QueueBufferDuration=956000, 
2020-01-27 06:53:35.328 4182-4262/ W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd48dd008 disconnect failed
2020-01-27 06:53:36.017 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:36.096 4182-4262/ D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-01-27 06:53:36.175 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:36.178 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:53:36.179 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setDisplayOrientation Failed: set display orientation failed
2020-01-27 06:53:36.181 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:36.978 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:53:36.990 4182-4182/ E/Camera: Error 2
2020-01-27 06:53:37.040 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:37.160 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1105ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=15593784036511, Vsync=15594767087327, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15594770152361, AnimationStart=15594770423902, PerformTraversalsStart=15594772051694, DrawStart=15594807059573, SyncQueued=15594846584202, SyncStart=15594846778160, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15594869251079, SwapBuffers=15594887089997, FrameCompleted=15594889647331, DequeueBufferDuration=7349000, QueueBufferDuration=1031000, 
2020-01-27 06:53:51.816 4182-4262/ W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd48dd008 disconnect failed
2020-01-27 06:53:52.497 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:52.568 4182-4262/ D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-01-27 06:53:52.655 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:52.659 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 0
2020-01-27 06:53:52.660 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setDisplayOrientation Failed: set display orientation failed
2020-01-27 06:53:52.661 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:53:53.166 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 0
2020-01-27 06:53:53.174 4182-4182/ E/Camera: Error 2
2020-01-27 06:53:53.209 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:53:53.333 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=781ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=15610280644733, Vsync=15610924712509, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15610938505568, AnimationStart=15610938769527, PerformTraversalsStart=15610940187027, DrawStart=15610980021989, SyncQueued=15611021218452, SyncStart=15611021401618, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15611042124829, SwapBuffers=15611058239997, FrameCompleted=15611062475581, DequeueBufferDuration=8643000, QueueBufferDuration=1439000, 
2020-01-27 06:54:33.415 4182-4262/ W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd48dd008 disconnect failed
2020-01-27 06:54:34.104 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:54:34.172 4182-4262/ D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-01-27 06:54:34.250 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:54:34.252 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:54:34.254 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setDisplayOrientation Failed: set display orientation failed
2020-01-27 06:54:34.256 4182-4182/ D/Camera: setPreviewTexture failed
2020-01-27 06:54:34.761 4182-4182/ D/Camera: Rotate 270
2020-01-27 06:54:34.774 4182-4182/ E/Camera: Error 2
2020-01-27 06:54:34.805 4182-4182/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-01-27 06:54:34.942 4182-4262/ I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=794ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=15651876176648, Vsync=15652520244424, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=15652534305206, AnimationStart=15652534506748, PerformTraversalsStart=15652537321040, DrawStart=15652583784419, SyncQueued=15652629034174, SyncStart=15652629455049, IssueDrawCommandsStart=15652650115843, SwapBuffers=15652667089970, FrameCompleted=15652670663762, DequeueBufferDuration=9324000, QueueBufferDuration=1607000, 
2020-01-27 07:03:10.639 4182-4262/ W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd48dd008 disconnect failed
```

As can be seen from the log, when the orientation changes, surfaceChanged callback gets called twice.  The first time, I get the setDisplayOrientation failed.  I'm not sure why I'm getting setPreviewTexture failed because I'm not even using TextureView.  I also don't know why I'm getting Error 2 for the camera either.  I have tried several solutions that I found here and elsewhere to no avail.  Here's the code in question:

```
    @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Display display;
    int rotation;
    int degrees = 0;
    int result;

    // If the holder is null, then just return.
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Stop the preview.
    try {
        if (isPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            isPreviewRunning = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Camera", "Stop Preview Failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // Check the device orientation.
    display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    rotation = display.getRotation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            Log.d("Camera", "Rotate 0");
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            Log.d("Camera", "Rotate 90");
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            Log.d("Camera", "Rotate 180");
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            Log.d("Camera", "Rotate 270");
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    // Not sure why this fails.  No reason given.
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Camera", "setDisplayOrientation Failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // Restart the preview with the new changes.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        isPreviewRunning = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Camera", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Despite the errors, it does work.  So should I just ignore the errors or continue to try to fix them?  I am writing for API level 19.  I know that Camera was depreciated in API 21, but older devices are still out there and I want this code to run on those as well.  As for the research, there seems to be [two main solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130447/android-camera-setdisplayorientation-does-not-work).  I have tried both and they do not work.  The one with the getParameters is telling me that getParameters failed that it returned null, which should not happen, but it does.

**Research:**

As for the research that I have done trying to fix this problem...

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/626862/Android-Camera-setDisplayOrientation-Failed

[Textureview/Surface view for Camera preview - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536564/textureview-surface-view-for-camera-preview-android)

[Problem with camera when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099032/problem-with-camera-when-orientation-changes)

[Android Camera setDisplayOrientation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130447/android-camera-setdisplayorientation-does-not-work)

[android camera setDisplayOrientation(90) fails in different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017148/android-camera-setdisplayorientation90-fails-in-different-devices)

[Set display orientation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259063/set-display-orientation-failed)